# can i open multiple popen without closing file-descriptor?

Tags: c, linux

Can i use same file descriptor, for multiple popen, without closing it, before calling next popen, in same function?
will it any memory leakage of any runtime error for long run? 
e.g.

```
    fun()
    { FILE *fd  = popen (some_command, "r");
      fd = popen (another_command, "r");
      fd = popen (another_command, "r");
      ... and so on..
      fclose(fd);   //at the end of the program 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that. You're losing the `FILE*` that the previous `popen` call returned so you will not be able to `pclose()` those. So this creates resource leaks, memory will not be released, and you risk not ever terminating the processes that gets started.

Note too that you should call `pclose()` instead of `fclose()`

Comment: Thanks nos for your answer.